# CakePHP mail not working on server

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I recently uploaded a CakePHP 2.3.8 app to a Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 instance and now I cannot send emails when using `$Email->send()` but I can do it with the "fast" method of `CakeEmail::deliver('to@gmail.com', 'Subject', 'Content');`, however I have a layout that I want to use.

When I try to send an email I get an error stating "Could not send email.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred."

Here is my code for sending the email.

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from(array('myemailaddress@gmail.com' => 'Me'));
$Email->to('person@gmail.com');
$Email->subject('Test Email');
$Email->template('layout_1');
$Email->emailFormat('html');
$testvalues = array('item1' => 'test1', 'item2' => 'test2');            
$Email->viewVars(array('tesvalues'=> $testvalues));
$Email->send();
$this->Session->setFlash('Email has been sent');
$this->redirect($this->referer(), null, true);
```

In /App/Config/email.php here is what I have for smtp

```
public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'from' => array('me@gmail.com' => 'Me'),
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'me@gmail.com',
    'password' => '****',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false,
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

The exact line that the stack trace flags is in CORE/Cake/Network/Email/MailTransport.php

```
$this->_mail($to, $email->subject(), $message, $headers, $params);
```

I checked the error log and it says

```
Error: [SocketException] Could not send email.
```

Comment: Are you able to use mail() function within that server? Have you checked CakePHP logs?

Comment: Can you be more specific as far as the mail function goes? I'm not sure what you're talking about. Is it a different way to send emails? Like I said, CakeEmail::deliver() works, but I'm not sure what mail() is . As far as the logs go, what specifically am I looking for? I just see the error "Error: [SocketException] Could not send email" followed by the stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to shoot in the dark here.

It seems to me that you are not setting the layout correctly, [according to the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-templated-emails) you need to tell cake the layout and the view you want to use, for example:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->template('welcome', 'fancy')
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->to('bob@example.com')
    ->from('app@domain.com')
    ->send();
```

The above would use app/View/Emails/html/welcome.ctp for the view, and app/View/Layouts/Emails/html/fancy.ctp for the layout.

Anyways, I recommend taking a look at Cake logs (app/tmp/logs) and see the cause of your error

Comment: I've already tried sending it without using a template and it still gives the error.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer above. It says "Error: [SocketException] Could not send email."

Comment: Based on that, it seems something related to the server configuration and not to CakePHP. That's why I told you before to write script that uses PHP mail() function and test it.

Comment: I can send it using CakeEmail::deliver() but I want to use my templates

Comment: I also deleted everything from App/Config/email.php just to see if it would say "smpt not found" or something. It still said Internal Error. However, when I deleted $fast and tried to send using CakeEmail::deliver() it then stated "Fast not found".

Comment: I got it to work. PHP mail() wasn't installed. I was able to send it using fast, so I didn't understand what you meant. Also, I didn't realize that it was a separate package that had to be installed.